# Color Changing Text JavaScript (Randomize on Timer)

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently work on a website page and im wanting to make a certain part of the page text change color randomly on a timer upload page loading..

Now i have come across something similar but it works from a button and i have tried so many times to get it working without the button and it just keeps breaking so heres the Code im basing all this off:

```js
var timerId;

    var ind = document.getElementById("indicator");
    var tit = document.getElementById("title");
    var color = ["red"]

    function startCycle() {
    timerId = setInterval(changeColor, 500);
    }

    function stopCycle() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = null;
    }

    function changeColor() {
    if (ind.innerHTML == 'blue') {
        tit.style.color = 'green';
        ind.innerHTML = 'green';
    }

    else if (ind.innerHTML == "green") {
        tit.style.color = 'yellow';
        ind.innerHTML = "yellow";
    }

    else {
        tit.style.color = 'blue';
        ind.innerHTML = "blue";
    }
    }
```

```html
    <button type="button" onclick="startCycle()">Start/Resume cycle</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="stopCycle()">Stop cycle</button>
    <div id="title">Colormatic!</div>
    It is currently
    <span id="indicator">blue</span>
```

Any type of help on this matter is very much appreciated Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the function to `window.onload`: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/uauvtoow/

Updated with (semi-) random colors. If you add more colors it will be more random.

```js
var timerId;

var ind = document.getElementById("indicator");
var tit = document.getElementById("title");
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange", "brown", "gray"];

window.onload = startCycle();

function startCycle() {
timerId = setInterval(changeColor, 500);
}

function stopCycle() {
clearInterval(timerId);
timerId = null;
}

function getColor(){
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
function changeColor() {
  let color = getColor();
  if(color == ind.innerHTML){
   color = getColor();
  }
  
  ind.innerHTML = color;
  tit.style.color = color;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="startCycle()">Start/Resume cycle</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stopCycle()">Stop cycle</button>
<div id="title">Colormatic!</div>
It is currently
<span id="indicator">blue</span>
```

Comment: Is there a way to i dont know... randomize the color like this site  [link](http://d3s.space/) as an Example of What Im trying to achive as this is what inspired me to do the colour changing text on a timer.

Answer (score 1):

simply call the function

```
startCycle();
```

somewhere, for example just directly in your javascript after you defined it - that will work because the javascript runs when its loaded

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thregon/ypbpLwtv/) with your code copy pasted

if you want other events to trigger the behaviour you can use event listeners,
you will find more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Answer (score 0):

You could doing it using `window.onload`:

```js
var timerId;

var ind = document.getElementById("indicator");
var tit = document.getElementById("title");
var color = ["red"];

window.onload = startCycle(); // When the site loads, call the function that starts the interval

function startCycle() {
timerId = setInterval(changeColor, 500);
}

function stopCycle() {
clearInterval(timerId);
timerId = null;
}

function changeColor() {
if (ind.innerHTML == 'blue') {
    tit.style.color = 'green';
    ind.innerHTML = 'green';
}

else if (ind.innerHTML == "green") {
    tit.style.color = 'yellow';
    ind.innerHTML = "yellow";
}

else {
    tit.style.color = 'blue';
    ind.innerHTML = "blue";
}
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="startCycle()">Start/Resume cycle</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stopCycle()">Stop cycle</button>
<div id="title">Colormatic!</div>
It is currently
<span id="indicator">blue</span>
```

---

Or you can do it via the `onload` attribute on the `body` tag:

```js
var timerId;

var ind = document.getElementById("indicator");
var tit = document.getElementById("title");
var color = ["red"];

function startCycle() {
  timerId = setInterval(changeColor, 500);
}

function stopCycle() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  timerId = null;
}

function changeColor() {
  if (ind.innerHTML == 'blue') {
    tit.style.color = 'green';
    ind.innerHTML = 'green';
  } else if (ind.innerHTML == "green") {
    tit.style.color = 'yellow';
    ind.innerHTML = "yellow";
  } else {
    tit.style.color = 'blue';
    ind.innerHTML = "blue";
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="startCycle()">
  <button type="button" onclick="startCycle()">Start/Resume cycle</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="stopCycle()">Stop cycle</button>
  <div id="title">Colormatic!</div>
  It is currently
  <span id="indicator">blue</span>
</body>
```

---

Or most simple: just call the `startCycle()` function:

```js
var timerId;

var ind = document.getElementById("indicator");
var tit = document.getElementById("title");
var color = ["red"];

startCycle(); // Call the function that starts the timer

function startCycle() {
  timerId = setInterval(changeColor, 500);
}

function stopCycle() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  timerId = null;
}

function changeColor() {
  if (ind.innerHTML == 'blue') {
    tit.style.color = 'green';
    ind.innerHTML = 'green';
  } else if (ind.innerHTML == "green") {
    tit.style.color = 'yellow';
    ind.innerHTML = "yellow";
  } else {
    tit.style.color = 'blue';
    ind.innerHTML = "blue";
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="startCycle()">Start/Resume cycle</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="stopCycle()">Stop cycle</button>
  <div id="title">Colormatic!</div>
  It is currently
  <span id="indicator">blue</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems author of the question is mostly interested in a way to automatically start and stop the color change. And there is no neseccity to put the color 'string' into innerHTML and use it as a data for the next color change.
I've added another (optimized) version of the code with comments.

```
<p id="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

<!--attach listener inline just for test purposes-->
<button onclick="updateColor(0)">Start</button>
<button onclick="stopColorChange()">Stop</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var text = document.getElementById('p'),
      // put all required colors into an array to loop though them easily
      colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange'],
      // specify the change duration
      changeTime = 600, //ms
      // global timerId
      timerId;

  /** 
   * Start color update. First Call should be with parameter 0 to use first 
   * color from a list
   */
  function updateColor(i) {
    // iterate thought the colors array until we reach the end of array and 
    // start loop again
    i = colors.length <= i ? 0 : i;
    text.style.color = colors[i];
    //update timerId each time to be able to stop it when 'stopColorChange' 
    //is called
    timerId = setTimeout(function() {
      updateColor(++i);
    }, changeTime);
  }

  /** 
   * Stop color update. Simply call this function when color change needs to 
   * stop
   */
  function stopColorChange() {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
  }

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/selevko/a7sot620/

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: My fault, I am new to stack... I've updated the answer and added comments in a code to clarify the details. Thanks for the note!